# How can I get all the cafes near me from google map with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get all the cafes near me from google map with javascript.

api google map

Comment: Hi! Could you please rewrite your question after you have shown a valid attempt at researching/solving your problem?

Comment: Look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235936/google-map-api-to-find-nearby-restaurant-around-my-place

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.